# Number of surjective functions where $f(a) = b$

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

Let $A,B$ be groups such that $\left | A \right | = 7$ $\left | B \right | = 5$  and let $a\in A$ and $b\in B$

Find the number of onto functions $f:A \mapsto B$ where $f(a) = b$

Using the inclusion - exclusion principle I found that all the surjective functions from $A$ to $B$ is $16,800$

My question is, should I treat somehow that $f(a) = b$ for $a\in A$ and $b\in B$?

Does it change the way I treat the question somehow? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've over-counted, since you've also counted those surjections $f : A \to B$ such that $f(a) \ne b$.

To count it properly, note that there are two possible cases. Either:

- $f(x) \ne b$ for any $x \ne a$. In this case, $f$ is uniquely determined by its restriction to a surjection $A \setminus \{ a \} \to B \setminus \{ b \}$; or
- $f(x) = b$ for some $x \ne a$. In this case, $f$ is uniquely determined by its restriction to a surjection $A \setminus \{ a \} \to B$.

So you need to count the number of surjections $A \setminus \{ a \} \to B \setminus \{ b \}$ and the number of surjections $A \setminus \{ a \} \to B$. The sum of these two values is what you seek.

Comment: How could I instead subract all the surjections $f : A \to B$ such that $f(a) \ne b$ ?

Comment: @vpam: You could also do that, but you'd need to consider whether the restriction of $f : A \to B$ to $A \setminus \{ a \}$ is surjective, which ultimately boils down to checking the two cases I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I am still not 100% sure why your method digs the right answer. Care elaborationg some more, or in a different way?

Comment: @vpam: I'm partitioning the set of surjections $A \to B$ with $f(a)=b$ into two subsets. The first subset is those for which $a$ is the only element of $A$ that $f$ sends to $b$; the second subset is those for which there are other elements of $A$ that $f$ sends to $b$. The sizes of these subsets can then be computed by making the observations in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Of all the surjective functions from $A$ onto $B$, what fraction have $f(a)=b$?

Comment: Im abit confused by that notion, is $a$ fixed? or arbitrary?
Could you please elaborate furthermore?

Comment: $a$ is some fixed member of $A$, and $b$ is some fixed member of $B$.  It doesn't matter which.